# How to add more files to a finalized DVD?

Tags: dvd, disk

I have a finalized DVD...but some documents were left to be put into the DVD. I want to burn the leftover files into that finalized disk. How to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of DVD? if it's just files you should be able to pop the DVD in and just burn more files... If it's a video then you're out of luck.

Comment: just files...please guide me through the required steps

Comment: I'm sorry, I got a little confused. Virusboy's answer is correct.

Comment: Okay...though it didn't fulfill my purpose and idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must copy the contents to your hard-drive then add the new files and re-burn. 
There is no way to edit any disc after finalizing it, even if its an -/+RW.  Make certain you do not finalize the disc so you can rewrite the same disc.